# How to render the options in a select of a Django form?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, materialize

I would like to render two selects with Django (one multiple select, the other a simple one) and customize it with Materialize. I managed to code the following:

In my forms.py

```
class ZonesForm(forms.Form):
    zones_options = (
        (1, 'Zone 1'),
        (2, 'Zone 2'),
        (3, 'Zone 3'),
        (4, 'Zone 4')
    )
    zones = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=zones_options)

    conn_options = (
        (1, 'ABCDE'),
        (2, 'FGHIJ'),
    )
    connections = forms.ChoiceField(choices=conn_options)
```

In my zones.html

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <select multiple name="{{ form.zones.name }}">
                    {% for opt in form.zones %}
                        <option value="{{ opt.id }}">{{ opt.label }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <label>Zones</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <select name="form.connections.name">
                    {% for opt in form.connections %}
                        <option value="{{ opt.id }}">{{ opt }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <label>Connection</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is: when the page is rendered, I get 4 checkboxes for the first select (as expected), and no names for it (all options are blank). For the second select I get 4 options (one blank, one with 'ABCDE', one blank, one with 'FGHIJ').

I suspect that the problem is with the attributes. I am not getting the right values for them (I have tried opt.label, opt.text, opt.choices, opt.value, opt...). How can I access them correctly?

Another question: is there a nice way to debug through it? I am new to Django and to web-dev in general. I tried *import pdb; pdb.set_trace()* to debug through it but I could not get pass my break point to navigate through other methods (I am using PyCharm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem and I am posting this answer in case someone faces a similar issue.

For the first select, in forms.py I replaced `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` with `widget=forms.SelectMultiple`. Surprisingly enough, the checkboxes are rendered correctly. I am not sure about the difference between `CheckboxSelectMultiple` and `SelectMultiple` but the later works =)

For both cases I had to change my zones.html. It looks like this now:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                {{ form.zones }}
                <label>Zones</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                {{ form.connections }}
                <label>Connection</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```